# LongClick is not Properly Working in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, buttonclick, onlongclicklistener

I given Long Click on Linear layout.Code is given below .Its working on Many devices.but not working on few devices Like Samsung Galaxy Tab E, SM-T561 .

activity_main layout,

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_accept"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_accept_24dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/new_accept"
                android:textColor="@color/new_accept_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/new_job_accept_reject_txt_size" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity() class,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnLongClickListener {
...........
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        .....................

        llAccept = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_accept);
        llAccept.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        ......................
}

 @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ll_accept:
                //do your need
                break;
             }       
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when long clicked from that device?

Comment: call is not coming inside the click

Answer (score 0):

longClicklistener need to return boolean, false if a click listener has to still execute after the long click and true if there are no further actions needed

Another solution could be adding clickable, focusable and other attributes like those to the LinearLayout.